# Bibliography using Texshop and Mendeley export

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texshop

Latex does not seem generate any bibliography. I use the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\citet{Blavatskyy2011}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
Undefined control sequence.
```

The    `library.bib` file is in the same directory as the    `.tex file`. I use TexShop on Mac OS X, the    `.bib` file is created with Menedeley. The exemplary entry is:

```
@article{Blavatskyy2011,
author = {Blavatskyy, Pavlo R.},
doi = {10.1287/mnsc.1100.1285},
file = {:Users/Chris/Desktop/Mendeley Desktop/2011\_Blavatskyy\_A Model of Probabilistic Choice Satisfying First-Order Stochastic Dominance\_Management Science.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0025-1909},
journal = {Management Science},
keywords = {2010,2011,accepted october 19,advance january 28,by peter wakker,decision analysis,first-order stochastic dominance,history,online in articles in,probabilistic choice,published,random utility,received march 8,strong utility},
month = mar,
number = {3},
pages = {542--548},
title = {{A Model of Probabilistic Choice Satisfying First-Order Stochastic Dominance}},
url = {http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.1100.1285},
volume = {57},
year = {2011}
```

What could be the problem? The Mendeley export? TexShop? Other?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which control sequence is undefined, but the problem is likely that you don't load the `natbib` package. The `\citet` command is not defined by the  LaTeX-core, so I guess that is the control sequence which is undefined. Hence, add

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

to the preamble.

You should also change the `\bibliographystyle` to `plainnat`, which is `natbib`s version of the `plain` style.

Comment: Also `plain` should be `plainnat`

Comment: Thanks, the code is now:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \citet{Blavatskyy2011}
    \bibliography{library}
    \end{document}
The error message in the    .log file is:
    Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations

Comment: Does the    .bib file entry look as it should?

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` after running `latex` (and after that you have to run `latex` twice).

Comment: By the way in the bibtex example you must have a closing `}` at the  end. I assume it is a problem with cut and paste.

Comment: @user3213255 With the exception of the lacking closing brace that Guido mentioned, the bib-entry is fine, it all works here.