# Incompatible month formats between biblatex and Mendeley

Tags: biblatex

As the title suggests, I'm using Mendeley as my reference manager (which automatically generates a `.bib` file for the entire bibliography) and `biblatex` with BibTeX as the backend to handle the bibliography. As I've seen in related threads, `biblatex` wants the month field as in integer between 1 and 12; however Mendeley only exports months as the standard 3 letter BibTeX-compatible abbreviation. Bearing in mind that I can't really play around with the `.bib` file as it's auto generated, is there any way I can get `biblatex` to play nice with three letter abbreviated months? (N.B. it still compiles, just throws a lot of warnings)

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\bibliography{mwebib}

\begin{document}

foo\cite{bar}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

With `mwebib.bib`

```
@article{bar,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  arxivId = {astro-ph.IM/1107.4806},
  author = {{The Pierre Auger Collaboration}},
  eprint = {1107.4806},
  journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
  month = {jul},
  primaryClass = {astro-ph.IM},
  title = {{The Pierre Auger Observatory IV: Operation and Monitoring}},
  year = {2011}
}
```

Comment: For those of us no using Mendeley, an example `.bib` entry would be handy. For example, I wonder if you mean that it's creating string entries of the form `month = jan`, which can then be defined as `@string{jan = "1"}`.

Comment: If you can use biber, it defines the standard macros internally and maps them to the biblatex numbers automatically.

Comment: Note that the proper way to give full dates in `biblatex` is the `date` field (in `YYYY-MM-DD` format - you may of course leave out the day or the month and day). But you can use the fields `year` and `month` for backwards compatibility. (You can, however, not give the full date using a `day` field, it will be ignored.) Would it be possible to show an example of what Mendeley exports?

Comment: I just tested the example from [Bibliography using Texshop and Mendeley export](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161363/35864) with both Biber and BibTeX and got the expected output with both back-ends (and no warnings or errors). So I will really need an example to understand what is going on. It would also be helpful if you could show us the warnings you get to see and whether you get unexpected output.

Comment: sorry all, I should have included a .bib:

`@article{bar,
 archivePrefix = {arXiv},
 arxivId = {astro-ph.IM/1107.4806},
 author = {{The Pierre Auger Collaboration}},
 eprint = {1107.4806},
 journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
 keywords = {Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena,Astrophysics - Instrumentation and Methods for Ast,High Energy Physics - Experiment,Physics - Instrumentation and Detectors},
 month = {jul},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.IM},
 title = {{The Pierre Auger Observatory IV: Operation and Monitoring}},
 year = {2011}
}`

Comment: here's the warning I get:

BibTeX reported the following issues(biblatex) with 'bar':(biblatex) - Invalid format of field 'month'.

whereabouts could I place the `@string{jan = "1"}` macro?

Comment: Thanks for the example, I added it to the question, so we have everything at one place.

Comment: Mhh, Mendeley's `.bib` export is a bit meh and has some troubles, but I'm really confused why you get `month = {jul},` in the examples on this site if found the correct `month = jul,`. Unfortunately, when I import the paper in your example, I don't get a month at all. Anyway `month = {jul},` is not the correct output, you might want to complain to the Mendeley guys about this. If you use Biber I could come up with an ugly work-around.

Comment: Turns out, with Biber you don't even need an ugly work-around, Biber is far smarter than I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard BibTeX abbreviations should not be given in braces, but bare as in

```
month = mar,
```

only then does BibTeX understand their special meaning.

You can read a bit about this in [Tame the Beast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) where we find (on p. 13)

> It's better having a numerical value, or an abbreviation, instead of the complete name of the month.

There it is not that clear that the abbreviation needs to be give without braces or quotation marks.

on p. 44 it says

> Namely, for instance, months should be entered numerically.

So `month = {jul},` is not the format recommended by Tame the Beast.

Have a look at the following BibTeX example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Blavatskyy2011,
  author = {Blavatskyy, Pavlo R.},
  doi = {10.1287/mnsc.1100.1285},
  month = mar,
  number = {3},
  pages = {542--548},
  title = {{A Model of Probabilistic Choice Satisfying First-Order Stochastic Dominance}},
  volume = {57},
  year = {2011},
}

@article{bar,
  author = {{The Pierre Auger Collaboration}},
  eprint = {1107.4806},
  journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
  month = {jul},
  title = {{The Pierre Auger Observatory IV: Operation and Monitoring}},
  year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
These are my works, \cite{Blavatskyy2011,bar}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The month wrapped in braces does not give the expected result.

[image: BibTeX example with plain.bst]

---

The same holds if you use `biblatex` with the BibTeX back-end.
The new back-end Biber is so clever that it can even deal with braced `month` fields

So the following MWE will give the expected output (with `backend=bibtex` though, it won't work as expected).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Blavatskyy2011,
  author = {Blavatskyy, Pavlo R.},
  doi = {10.1287/mnsc.1100.1285},
  month = mar,
  number = {3},
  pages = {542--548},
  title = {{A Model of Probabilistic Choice Satisfying First-Order Stochastic Dominance}},
  volume = {57},
  year = {2011},
}

@article{bar,
  author = {{The Pierre Auger Collaboration}},
  eprint = {1107.4806},
  journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
  month = {jul},
  title = {{The Pierre Auger Observatory IV: Operation and Monitoring}},
  year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
These are my works, \cite{Blavatskyy2011,bar}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex example with Biber]

---

Even though Biber has no problems with the file exported from Mendeley I still consider the export faulty, since BibTeX cannot properly deal with this.

So if you cannot change the `.bib` file and still want to get rid of the warnings you should try and use Biber.

Comment: thanks for that; unfortunately that's what I was expecting. I've switched over to biber now:

\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}

and am running

pdflatex
biber
pdflatex
pdflatex.
however now when I run biber, every single \cite command throws the warning

Citation 'wulf1909' on page 1 undefined
etc. I've deleted the .bbl and .aux files, are there any other changes I need to make? the .bib file is the same as before.

Comment: @user95308 If you really run Biber (if you use an editor, [check the configuration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)) and have `\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}` everything should work especially if you got rid of the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf`. Note that you need tor run Biber on the `.bcf` file, not the `.aux` file (or better yet: leave the file ending and let Biber figure it out). See also [this go-to question for problems such as this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: @user95308 Check also if you can get `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}` to work. Check what the `.blg` file says.

Comment: I use texstudio, so I've configured it to use the chain I previously mentioned (pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex). my .blg file tells me
`I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux`

Comment: @user95308 If you get that error you are *definitely* not running Biber but BibTeX. Please refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for the correct setup of Biber in your editor.

Comment: as per my previously comment, i've instructed texstudio to run `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`, ensuring that biblatex is running with Biber via \usepackage[packend=biber]{biblatex}, and I've also deleted all build files. I also get the warning `WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.9, expected version 2.5`, could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Turns out that that version mismatch WAS the problem - manually replacing `biber.exe` in `../miktex/bin` with the latest version from `http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber` seems to have fixed everything.

Comment: @user95308 It is normally better to let your TeX distribution (TeX live: `tlmgr` or MikTeX: Updater) do the update to make sure all the package versions match. But if it works now, I suppose its fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use python to change the month field in the bib file. Put python code file in the folder of your bib file. Then run `python code_file.py bib_file.bib`

```
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
 
import sys
import re
 
def replace(file_path):
  try:
    f = open(file_path,'r+')
    all_lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    re_pattern = re.compile(r'month = {(?P<month>[^}]*)}')
    for line in all_lines:
      line = re_pattern.sub(r'month = \g<month>', line)
      f.write(line)
    f.close()
  except Exception:
    print("something wrong!") 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    print("need filename")
    sys.exit(1)
  file_name = sys.argv[1]
  replace(file_name)
```