# Output Bibtex From Mendeley Issue

Tags: bibtex

So I have a typical BibTeX output that from Mendeley looks like this,

```
@article{Shimada2010,
author = {Shimada, K and Nakanii, N and Murata, I and Habara, H and Tanaka, K a},
doi = {10.1088/1742-6596/244/3/032059},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/der24683/Desktop/Work/Papers/Organised/Shimada et al. - 2010 - Measurement of fast neutron by using imaging plate.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1742-6596},
journal = {Journal of Physics: Conference Series},
month = {aug},
number = {3},
pages = {032059},
title = {{Measurement of fast neutron by using imaging plate}},
url = {http://stacks.iop.org/1742-6596/244/i=3/a=032059?key=crossref.6e5d2b330a7c31fb1508f0bc6d2241a3},
volume = {244},
year = {2010}
}
```

My issue is with the month. This output as `aug` and not `Aug`.

I can go through and manually change the months to capitals (like this `{Aug}`) however this is take ages.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Deanio13

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Related [Incompatible month formats between biblatex and Mendeley](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286261/106162) although I don't think it necessarily solves your question (unless [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is an option?).  Note `month=mar` is how the value should be entered, the month is then formatted according to the bibliography style used.

Comment: Use the find&replace tool of your editor to replace all `{aug}` with `aug` etc. This are twelve operations and your are done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a very dirty, but simple workaround: open the bibfile in a text editor (e.g. wordpad) and simply replace each aug by Aug by selecting the "entire word" and "identical capitalisation" options. My translation of the latter terms might be off, since I'm using a Dutch version of windows.